# c#: parse decimals using different styles

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I'm playing with decimal parsing and I've encountered something that I could not explain by reading the msdn documentation:
This code returns false:

```
decimal.TryParse(" 1.1", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d)
```

But this code returns true:

```
decimal.TryParse(" 1.1", out d)
```

But from what I've read on msdn, `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` has to do only with the separator, so why the first version of the code fails to parse the decimal string?

Comment: What happens if you trim off the space? Same results?

Comment: This works: `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite`

Comment: From the docs `Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style` which includes leading and trailing whitespace and negative signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the MSDN documentation for [decimal.TryParse(string,decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) explains in the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) section:

> Parameter s is interpreted using the [NumberStyles.Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) style.

This is a flag that :

> Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.

The [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs,56) is actually easier to read:

```
Number   = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign | AllowTrailingSign |
           AllowDecimalPoint | AllowThousands,
```

Answer (score 5):

Your first example does not include `AllowLeadingWhite` in the `NumberStyles`. Since your string has whitespace and you aren't allowing it, the parse fails.

Comment: And `AllowLeadingWhite` is probably the default in the second example, for better or for worse (it should be consistent, in my opinion).

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse(" 1.1", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d));`

Comment: @rory.ap the default style is [NumberStyles.Number](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs,56) which is very permissive